# How to send a filename through batch & accept it in Java

Tags: java, batch-file, batch-processing

Ok so I might have worded this wrong, it's a little difficult to explain. So here goes:
Main Goal: Call java triangle program through batch while also piping a list of testcase.txt files with input that must be sent to the java program to determine the triangle type. WITHOUT hard typing the file name into the java program.

Problem:Not sure how to accept the fileName to use in the java application from the batch command window.

Currently, I'm just using one text file to test with containing 3 numbers separated by a space. When running the java program by itself I can type the file path to the text file & everything works as intended. But alas I can't hard code or ask the user for that path since this should be setup by the batch file to call these 15 test case files to send to the program. The part of code I have now that I dont understand is this:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = input.next();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (new File(fileName));
```

So I understand that input.next() is going to be asking for keyboard input how can I switch this from keyboard input to batch file input? If that makes sense.

Here is my batch file:

```
@ECHO off

set /P num1="Please enter file path: "

echo You entered %num1%
ECHO Checking for file...
if exist %num1% (
    set num1=Congrats! I found the file!
    C:\Users\josh\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Triangle\src\TriangleRebuild.java
) else (set num1=File does not exist)

echo %num1%

PAUSE


exit
```

Full Code:

```
/*
 * Josh 

Software Engineering

Structured Triangle Implementation in Java

 */
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TriangleRebuild {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = input.next();
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (new File(fileName));


        int a;

        int b;

        int c;

        boolean isATriangle;

        System.out.println("Enter 3 integers which are sides of a triangle: ");

        a = reader.nextInt();

        b = reader.nextInt();

        c = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Side A is: " + a);

        System.out.println("Side B is: " + b);

        System.out.println("Side C is: " + c);



        if((a < b + c) && (b < a + c) && (c < a + b)){

            isATriangle = true;

        } 

        else{

            isATriangle = false;

        }

        if(isATriangle){

            if((a == b) && (b == c)){

                System.out.println("Triangle is Equilateral.");

            }

            else if((a != b) && (a != c) && (b != c)){

                System.out.println("Triangle is Scalene.");

            }

            else{

                System.out.println("Triangle is Isosceles.");

            }

        }

        else{

            System.out.println("Not a Triangle.");

        }

        if((Math.pow(c,2) == Math.pow(a,2) + Math.pow(b,2))){

            System.out.println("Triangle is a right Triangle.");

        }

        else{

            System.out.println("Triangle is not a right Triangle.");

        }







    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that every `main` method is declared like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {...}
```

That `args` array represents command line arguments. That is, parameters you wrote on the `java` command line in your `cmd` window or your batch. So for example, if you have a line in your batch that says:

```
java TriangleRebuild abc.txt
```

Then inside the program, the array `args` will have the value `{ "abc.txt" }`. You can access that by using `args[0]`. You have to make sure, of course, that `args.length > 0` and that `args[0] != null` before you use it, just in case someone forgot to write the file name on the command line.

You can pass several file names in the command line.

```
java TriangleRebuild abc.txt def.txt hij.txt
```

And then your array will be: `{"abc.txt","def.txt","hij.txt"}` inside the program.

This way, you can pass argument from your batch to your Java and process them without interaction with the user.

Comment: Perfect, I wasn't even thinking about this! Works exactly as I intended! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet will likely be as follows: have the Batch file pipe the text file locations, as if they were input in a command line. Then, use those command line arguments to call the main method of your java class (simply invoke it like you would from the command line, with all of your batch input as the Args). Once inside the main method, do with them as you wish.